# When is multiplication $A \otimes_{A \cap B} B \to R$ an isomorphism onto its image?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, tensor-products

Let $R$ be a unital ring and $A$ and $B$ unital subrings of $R$ (not necessarily commutative). Then $A$ and $B$ are both bimodules over $A \cap B$ and I was wondering what conditions (if any) have to be met in order for 
$$A \otimes_{A \cap B} B \to R, a \otimes b \mapsto ab $$
to be an isomorphism onto its image (i.e. injective).

This question came to my mind while thinking about the analogue situation in group theory where 
$$ A \times_{A \cap B} B \to G, [a,b] \mapsto ab$$ 
for subgroups $A,B \subseteq G$ is always an isomorphism onto its image $AB$.
The group rings and their subrings generated by subgroups are thus examples where the above
morphism is an isomorphism onto its image.

Comment: Are you sure about your example with group rings? It does not seem that clear to me that it follows from the group case.

Comment: @CaptainLama : Maybe I am missing something. Suppose $k$ is a commutative unital ring. Then we have $k(A \times_{A \cap B} B) \cong kA \otimes_{k (A \cap B)} kB$, right? And for any map between sets $S \to T$, if this map is injective, then so is $kS \to kT$, right? Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Thinking twice, you're right about that derivation, presuming $A\times_{A\cap B} B$ means the amalgamated sum (since $G\mapsto k[G]$ is a left adjoint, it preserves colimits), but it's actually the group case which is incorrect. You can't compute $AB$ knowing just $A$, $B$ and $A\cap B$, since even when $A\cap B$ is trivial, $AB$ may be a direct product, a semi-direct product, etc.

Comment: @CaptainLama : I am not suggesting that $AB$ is a group. Actually, in most cases it is not. The correct counter-part to (bi)modules is sets with group actions and I am considering $AB$ as a set with a left $A$-action and a right $B$-action. Also, with $A \times_{A \cap B} B$ I denote the quotient of $A \times B$ modulo the action of $A \cap B$ given by $x (a,b) = (a x, x^{-1}b)$ for $x \in A \cap B$, $a \in A$ and $b \in B$. $A \times_{A \cap B} B$. It also has a natural left $A$-action and right $B$-action.